# Auto format on load and save in visual studio or git?

Tags: git, visual-studio, format

I'm working with a team of developers all who have differing code styles.

Is there a way to have code auto-formatted on load, then auto-formatted to a DIFFERENT style on save?

By having everyone format the same way on save the diffs in the repository are not so huge.

Ideally when we git pull, a process would auto-format to the local developers style, then on git push, it would auto-format to the accepted checked in style.

Answer (score 1):

You can use smudge and filter to do it.

---

### ***`Smudge / clean`***

Read all about it and to set it up here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

> It turns out that you can write your own filters for doing substitutions in files on **commit/checkout**.
>
> These are called `clean` and `smudge` filters.
>
> In the `.gitattributes` file, you can set a filter for particular paths and then set up scripts that will process files just before they’re checked out (“smudge”, see Figure 8-2) and just before they’re staged (“clean”, see Figure 8-3).
>
> These filters can be set to do all sorts of fun things.

[image]

Comment: when I do a git config --global filter.indent.clean mybat.bat  I get a "error: cannot feed the input to external filter mybat.bat"